# For studying languages / to study languages

Tags: prepositions

Don't know which sentence to use, to study a language from someone.

1. I want to find someone for studying languages.
2. I want to find someone to study languages.
3. I want to find someone to learn languages/for learning languages.

Comment: For future reference, it seems that this question is confused about the uses of the prepositions **for** and **to**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are correct sentences, but they each have different meanings. If you're the one learning the language, then you would say:

> I want to find someone for studying languages.

While if you are looking for someone else to study languages (i.e. you're going to make them study languages) you'd say:

> I want to find someone to study languages.

You can, for the most part, use "learn" and "study" interchangeably here.

Even though your sentences aren't wrong, it would be better to say:

> I want to find someone to help me study languages.

Comment: can I use I am looking for someone one to teach me languages.please tell me which sentence is formal.

Comment: You can use that, yes. For formality, you would probably want to say something along the lines of what you just said ("I am looking for someone to teach me languages") because "want" is generally not considered formal. Sorry for not originally including this in the answer, you hadn't specified that you wanted formal sentences.

Answer (score 0):

All of these are somewhat ambiguous or awkward.  A better phrasing would be:

> I want to find someone to teach me languages.

This indicates clearly that the speaker is the one who desires to learn languages.

Comment: are you saying that:"I am looking for someone to teach me languages " is also awkward.

Comment: @sac both "I am looking ... to teach me" and "I want to find ... to teach me" have the same level of awkwardness (that is, not much; they're both fine).